# Comparing Objects in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Ok so Im building a product sorting watch and this is what I have so far.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// starter jQuery file


 /* Watches Array */
    var watchesArray = [
        {
          model: "Swim", 
          image:"",
          price: 149.99,
          sports:["Swimming"],
          touchScreen:false,
          GPS:false,
          heartRateMonitor:false,
          hrZoneTraining:false,
          caloriesBurned:true,
          distance:true,
          pace:true,
          multisport:false,
          swimMetrics:true,
          memory:"Up to 30 workouts",
          virtualPartner:false,
          virtualRacer:false,
          paceAlert:false,
          timeDistanceAlert:false,
          hydrationAlert:false,
          rechargeableBattery:false,
          waterResistant:"Up to 50 meters",
          syncWithComputer:true,
          other:"",
        },
        {
          model: "FR 10", 
          image:"fr_10.jpg",
          price: 129.99,
          sports:["Running"],
          touchScreen:false,
          GPS:true,
          heartRateMonitor:false,
          hrZoneTraining:false,
          caloriesBurned:false,
          distance:true,
          pace:true,
          multisport:false,
          swimMetrics:false,
          memory:"Up to 7 workouts",
          virtualPartner:false,
          virtualRacer:false,
          paceAlert:false,
          timeDistanceAlert:false,
          hydrationAlert:false,
          rechargeableBattery:true,
          waterResistant:"Up to 50 meters",
          syncWithComputer:false,
          other:"-Virtual Pacer(compares running pace to target)</br>-Walk/Run feature",
          checkBox:"<input type='checkbox' name='he' value='jk' id='compare'>"

        },
        {
          model: "FR 15", 
          image:"fr_15.jpg",
          price: 199.99,
          sports:["Running"],
          touchScreen:false,
          GPS:true,
          heartRateMonitor:true,
          hrZoneTraining:true,
          caloriesBurned:true,
          distance:true,
          pace:true,
          multisport:false,
          swimMetrics:false,
          memory:"Up to 7 workouts",
          virtualPartner:false,
          virtualRacer:false,
          paceAlert:false,
          timeDistanceAlert:false,
          hydrationAlert:false,
          rechargeableBattery:true,
          waterResistant:"Up to 50 meters",
          syncWithComputer:false,
          other:"-Virtual Pacer (compares running pace to target) </br>Walk/Run  feature</br>-Activity",
        },
        {
          model: "FR 220", 
          image:"fr_220.jpg",
          price: 299.99,
          sports:["Running"],
          touchScreen:false,
          GPS:true,
          heartRateMonitor:true,
          hrZoneTraining:true,
          caloriesBurned:true,
          distance:true,
          pace:true,
          multisport:false,
          swimMetrics:false,
          memory:"200 hours of data",
          virtualPartner:false,
          virtualRacer:false,
          paceAlert:true,
          timeDistanceAlert:false,
          hydrationAlert:true,
          rechargeableBattery:true,
          waterResistant:"Up to 50 meters",
          syncWithComputer:true,
          other:"-Walk/Run feature</br>-Interval Training",
        },
        {
          model: "FR 620", 
          image:"fr_620.jpg",
          price: 449.99,
          sports:["Running"],
          touchScreen:true,
          GPS:true,
          heartRateMonitor:true,
          hrZoneTraining:true,
          caloriesBurned:true,
          distance:true,
          pace:true,
          multisport:false,
          swimMetrics:false,
          memory:"200 hours of data",
          virtualPartner:true,
          virtualRacer:false,
          paceAlert:true,
          timeDistanceAlert:true,
          hydrationAlert:true,
          rechargeableBattery:true,
          waterResistant:"Up to 50 meters",
          syncWithComputer:true,
          other:"-VO2 Max</div></br>-Walk/Run feature</br>-Interval Training",
        },
        {
          model: "FR 310 XT", 
          image:"",
          price: 349.99,
          sports:["Multisport"],
          touchScreen:false,
          GPS:true,
          heartRateMonitor:true,
          hrZoneTraining:true,
          caloriesBurned:true,
          distance:true,
          pace:true,
          multisport:true,
          swimMetrics:false,
          memory:"1000 laps",
          virtualPartner:true,
          virtualRacer:true,
          paceAlert:true,
          timeDistanceAlert:true,
          hydrationAlert:true,
          rechargeableBattery:true,
          waterResistant:"Up to 50 meters",
          syncWithComputer:true,
          other:"-Interval Training",
        },
        {
          model: "FR70", 
          image:"",
          price: 149.99,
          sports:["Fitness"],
          touchScreen:false,
          GPS:false,
          heartRateMonitor:true,
          hrZoneTraining:true,
          caloriesBurned:true,
          distance:true,
          pace:true,
          multisport:false,
          swimMetrics:false,
          memory:"Up to 20 hrs of data",
          virtualPartner:true,
          virtualRacer:false,
          paceAlert:true,
          timeDistanceAlert:true,
          hydrationAlert:false,
          rechargeableBattery:false,
          waterResistant:"Up to 50 meters",
          syncWithComputer:true,
          other:"-Interval Training",
        },
    ];

/* End Watch Array */

/* different sports arrays filtered */

var runningArray = watchesArray.filter(function(watch) {
            return watch.sports.indexOf('Running') !== -1;
        });
var swimmingArray = watchesArray.filter(function(watch) {
            return watch.sports.indexOf('Swimming') !== -1;
        });
var multisportArray = watchesArray.filter(function(watch) {
            return watch.sports.indexOf('Multisport') !== -1;
        });
var fitnessArray = watchesArray.filter(function(watch) {
            return watch.sports.indexOf('Fitness') !== -1;
        });

function compare() {
    if ($('#page-2 div:nth-of-type(1)').hasClass('running-category')) {
        var sportArray = runningArray;
    }
    if ($('#page-2 div:nth-of-type(2)').hasClass('swimming-category')) {
        var sportArray = swimmingArray;
    }
    if ($('#page-2 div:nth-of-type(3)').hasClass('multisport-category')) {
        var sportArray = multisportArray;
    }
    if ($('#page-2 div:nth-of-type(4)').hasClass('fitness-category')) {
        var sportArray = fitnessArray;
    }


    var sportArrayLength = $(sportArray).length;

    for (var i = 0; i < sportArrayLength; i++) {
        var watchModel = "<div class='watch-model'>"+sportArray[i].model+"</div>",
        watchImage = "<div class='watch-image'>"+sportArray[i].image+"</div>",
        watchPrice = "<div class='watch-price'>$"+sportArray[i].price+"</div>",
        watchSports = "<div class='watch-sports'>"+sportArray[i].sports+"</div>",
        watchTouch = "<div class='watch-touch'>"+sportArray[i].touchScreen+"</div>",
        watchGPS = "<div class='watch-gps'>"+sportArray[i].GPS+"</div>",
        watchHeart = "<div class='watch-heart'>"+sportArray[i].heartRateMonitor+"</div>",
        watchHRZone = "<div class='watch-zone'>"+sportArray[i].hrZoneTraining+"</div>",
        watchCalories = "<div class='watch-calories'>"+sportArray[i].caloriesBurned+"</div>",
        watchDistance = "<div class='watch-distance'>"+sportArray[i].distance+"</div>",
        watchPace = "<div class='watch-pace'>"+sportArray[i].pace+"</div>",
        watchMultiSport = "<div class='watch-swim-metrics'>"+sportArray[i].multisport+"</div>",
        watchSwimMetrics = "<div class='watch-multi'>"+sportArray[i].multisport+"</div>",
        watchMemory = "<div class='watch-memory'>"+sportArray[i].memory+"</div>",
        watchVirtualPartner = "<div class='watch-virtual-partner'>"+sportArray[i].virtualPartner+"</div>",
        watchVirtualRacer = "<div class='watch-virtual-racer'>"+sportArray[i].virtualRacer+"</div>",
        watchPaceAlert = "<div class='watch-pace-alert'>"+sportArray[i].paceAlert+"</div>",
        watchTimeDistanceAlert = "<div class='watch-time-distance-alert'>"+sportArray[i].timeDistanceAlert+"</div>",
        watchHydrationAlert = "<div class='watch-hydration'>"+sportArray[i].hydrationAlert+"</div>",
        watchRechargeable = "<div class='watch-rechargeable'>"+sportArray[i].rechargeableBattery+"</div>",
        watchWaterResistance = "<div class='watch-water-resistance'>"+sportArray[i].waterResistant+"</div>",
        watchSync = "<div class='watch-syncs'>"+sportArray[i].syncWithComputer+"</div>",
        watchOther = "<div class='watch-other'>"+sportArray[i].other+"</div>",
        watchesTotal ="<div class='item-container'>"+ watchModel + watchImage + watchPrice + watchSports + watchTouch + watchGPS + watchHeart + watchHRZone + watchCalories + watchDistance + watchPace + watchMultiSport + watchSwimMetrics + watchMemory + watchVirtualPartner + watchVirtualRacer + watchPaceAlert + watchTimeDistanceAlert + watchHydrationAlert + watchRechargeable + watchWaterResistance + watchSync + watchOther+"</div>" 
         ;

         $('.comparison-container').append(watchesTotal);
        // alert(watchModel)
    }

} //end function

$("#page-4 .continue-button").click(function() {
  $('.comparison-container').empty();
    compare();
 });




   //var inArray = $.inArray(true, watchesArray[0].multisport)
  // alert(inArray)




}); // ready method
```

So the flow is basically click a sport, filter through the array and make new array with only those items that have that sport, then select a som features that you which to have and when click continue those items that meet the criteria are displayed.

For the last part which is where I am stuck is that when those watches are displayed I have to be able to select a checkbox of those products that interest me so I can then continue and have those selected watches display with all of their details. So basically I need to figure out how to compare two objects from an array by selecting the ones that I want from the page.

On Page 3 you basically have a list of the array items and a compare checkbox under each one.I just need to be able to pass on those products that were selected to the next page

Comment: A suggestion to increase your code readability (helps you debugging and helps people understanding your code): you can use [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and give multiple classes to [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/), like this: `$('#page-3, #page-4, #page-5').removeClass('running-background fitness-background multisport-background swimming-background');`

Comment: Could you reduce your code to just the part that's relevant to the question? Is all the `removeClass` stuff important?

Comment: Posting some HTML would help too.

Answer (score -2):

> how to compare two objects from an array

Use `JSON.stringify` to compare the literals:

```
var foo = [{"1":2},{"1":3},{"2":3},{"1":2}];
var bar = JSON.stringify(foo[0]) === JSON.stringify(foo[1]);
var baz = JSON.stringify(foo[0]) === JSON.stringify(foo[3]);
```

Use an array as the second param to guarantee ordering of the key enumeration:

```
(JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2}, ["a","b"]) === JSON.stringify({b: 2, a: 1}, ["a","b"]))
```

Comment: @DavidKnipe You can delete it, fix it, or ignore it. `(JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2}) === JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2}))` is true everywhere I've tested, and the scenario posted above is not part of the question.

Comment: I can't delete it because it's not my answer, I can't fix it because it's fundamentally flawed, and it's better to warn people of wrong answers rather than ignore them. soktinpk has given a simple example for clarity, but the same principle could apply to the data in the question. And even if OP remembers never to define objects with keys in different orders, the output order may depend on obscure factors such as whether it's too busy for non-essential memory management (reallocating memory in hash tables). Anyway, you haven't tested everywhere and the js spec doesn't guarantee ordering.

Comment: @DavidKnipe Using an array for the second param enforces order, as per ES5-15.12.3:4.b.2, so `(JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2}, ["a","b"]) === JSON.stringify({b: 2, a: 1}, ["a","b"]))` works as expected. The [official spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) is currently down, but the [drafts](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=es3.1:es3.1_proposal_working_draft) and [historical discussion](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=proposals:json_encoding_and_decoding#commentsdiscussion) are available for reference.

Comment: I didn't know that. It seems to work. But it's a lot more unwieldy for data such as the original question than it is for your example. You'd need an array `['model','image',...,'other']` for the argument to `stringify`. You'd have to make sure it included all the keys in the objects, as well as keys in subobjects; otherwise it would silently ignore unlisted keys, potentially outputting the same JSON string for two non-isomorphic objects. For example, they might add a black version of one of the watches by cloning the object and adding `"colour": "black"` without adding "colour" to the array.

Comment: @DavidKnipe In the more complex case, the second param can also be a function call which returns an array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63639/discussion-between-david-knipe-and-paul-sweatte).